# Why run() method defined is not called on call of start by Thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I was just experimenting some code around Thread class and I get stuck at something, Well firstly have a look at my code

```
class ThreadExample implements Runnable
{
String threadName;
Thread thread;
public ThreadExample()
    {
    thread=new Thread();
    thread.start();
    }
public void run()
    {
    System.out.println("Thread "+getThreadName()+" is being executed");
    }
void setThreadName(String string)
    {
    threadName=string;
    thread.setName(string);
    }
String getThreadName()
    {
    return thread.getName();
    }
public static void main(String string[]) throws InterruptedException
    {
    ThreadExample threadExample= new ThreadExample();
    threadExample.setThreadName("Thread !");
    //threadExample=new ThreadExample();
    //threadExample.setThreadName("Thread 2");
    //threadExample=new ThreadExample();
    //threadExample.setThreadName("Thread 3");
    Thread.sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Well I think this code is very simple and Everyone should have got my intentions although When I am running this program It just get complete without even calling `run()`  method even I make main Thread to wait for sometime until the child Thread which is ThreadExample completes. I am new to this so sorry if I have forgotten some thing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi  Well I don't think so, but it would be great if you elaborate your view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You created a `Runnable` type and never passed it into a thread context. You'll want to add it to the Thread. I would do something like:

```
String threadName;
Thread thread;
public ThreadExample() {
    thread=new Thread(this);
}

public void startThread() {
   thread.start();
}
```

The `Thread` class accepts a `Runnable` as an argument.

Comment: Yeah brother I forgot to add this. Well as I have said I am new to Threads so it would take time for me to remember things like this. Thank you brother. Best of luck. I will accept this answer after 10 minutes.

Comment: @DushyantSuthar My pleasure, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

To run this implementation class, create a Thread object, pass Runnable implementation class object to its constructor. Call start() method on thread class to start executing run() method.
You missed following two lines:

> Thread thread1 = new Thread(threadExample);
>           thread1.start();

```
   class ThreadExample implements Runnable
    {
    String threadName;
    Thread thread;
    public ThreadExample()
        {           
        }
    public void run()
        {
        System.out.println("Thread "+getThreadName()+" is being executed");
        }
    void setThreadName(String string)
        {
        threadName=string;
        thread.setName(string);
        }
    String getThreadName()
        {
        return thread.getName();
        }
    public static void main(String string[]) throws InterruptedException
        {
        ThreadExample threadExample= new ThreadExample();
        threadExample.setThreadName("Thread !");
        //threadExample=new ThreadExample();
        //threadExample.setThreadName("Thread 2");
        //threadExample=new ThreadExample();
        //threadExample.setThreadName("Thread 3");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(threadExample);
        thread1.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: No brother have a look at the answer below your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You never call run() method. You rather call start, which you are already doing in ThreadExample() constructor, but it has some mistakes I will explain:

In java you have 2 options to deal with Threads. First is to inherit from Thread class, so you can call `start()` method from it and the code inside `run()` will be executed. The second option is to create a Runnable, which seems the option you are choosing, but to run this you have to create a Thread like this:

```
ThreadExample runnable = new ThreadExample();
Thread myThread = new Thread(threadExample);
```

And then you can call `myThread.start();` when you are ready to start your thread.

Comment: Have a look at accepted answer. Well thanks for your answer you were close enough though.

Answer (score 0):

As John Vint has pointed out, the Thread class needs a Runnable target. I edited your program a little :

```
public class NewThreadExample implements Runnable{

    String threadName;

    public String getThreadName() {
        return threadName;
    }

    public void setThreadName(String threadName) {
        this.threadName = threadName;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        NewThreadExample threadTarget = new NewThreadExample();
        threadTarget.setThreadName("Dushyant");

        Thread thread = new Thread(threadTarget);
        System.out.println("Thread created and going to start");
        thread.start();
        System.out.println("Thread sleeping");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Program done");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(this.getThreadName() + " is running...");
    }

}
```

gives

> Thread created and going to start
>
> Thread sleeping
>
> Dushyant is running...
>
> Program done

Comment: Yeah it also solves the problem but I was looking for the code in constructor so I don't want to make threads at main method. Well your presentation is pretty good. All the best friend.